# $4x^2+2xy+y^2+x+y+6\sqrt{xy}=15$ and $x+\frac{6(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}-\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}=3$

Tags: systems-of-equations

Solve the system of equations
$$\begin{align}
 4x^2+2xy+y^2+x+y+6\sqrt{xy}=15 \\
 x+\frac{6(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}-\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}=3
\end{align}$$
The only solution is $x=y=1$.
But I can't solve this. 
We can have this: $$3\bigg(\frac{6(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}-\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}-3\bigg)^2+(x+y)^2+x+y+6\sqrt{xy}=15$$
It is very difficult to use inequality here

Comment: @Moo I don't think it is equivalent to the original system.  $$(x;y)=(1.9; 1)$$ is another root

Comment: @Moo You can check their graphs on geogebra